# Show that it is not true in general that for any sets A,B, one has P(A union B) is a subset of P(A) union P(B)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that it is not true in general that

(i) for any sets A,B, one has P(A union B) is a subset of P(A) union P(B)

Show that it is true in general that

(ii) for any sets A , B , one has P(A) union P(B) is a subset of P(A union B).

For part (i) and part (ii), can you help me verify my proof? i didnt use elements for my answers as the question is to show in general so i did it this way.

(i) For any sets A , B ,

Consider the case A is not a subset of B.

Then , A union B will have more elements than A and more elements than B. Hence the power set of A union B will contain a set that has more elements than A or B.

Hence, P(A union B) is not a subset of P(A) union P(B).

(ii) I got 4 cases to consider.

Consider both the case A is not a subset of B and A is not equal to B.

Then, both cases will have the same argument that A union B will have more elements than A and more elements than B. Hence, the power set of (A union B) will contain a set that has more elements than A or B. Hence, P(A) union P(B) is a subset of P(A union B).

Consider the case A is a subset of B.

If A is a subset of B, thus A union B = B. Therefore, all the elements in A union B will be inside B. Thus the power set of (A union B) will be the same as the power set of B.
Also since A is a subset of B, elements in A will be in B as well. Therefore, Power set of A is a subset of Power set of B. Since Power set of A is a subset of Power set of B, power set of (A union B) equals to power set of B, thus, P(A U B) = P(B) = P(A) U P(B),
hence P(A) U P(B) is a subset of P(A U B).

Consider the case B is a subset of A.

If B is a subset of A, thus A U B = A. Therefore all the elements in A U B will be in A. Thus the power set of ( A U B ) will be the same as P ( A ).
Also , since B is a subset of A, elements in B will be in A as well. Therefore, P( B ) is a subset of P ( A ). Since P(B) is a subset of P(A), P(A) U P(B) = P(A). 
Thus, P(A U B) = P(A) = P(A) U P(B),
hence P(A) U P(B) is a subset of P(A U B).

*Do i need to consider the case of null sets?*

Comment: I assume here that $P()$ is the power set). For (i) I would suggest trying to find a counterexample, by finding a situation where you have an element of $P(A\cup B)$ that is neither a subset of $A$ nor of $B$.  For (ii) you might want to think about what it means for $S$ to be an element of $P(A)\cup P(B)$. (You don't need to do a proof by cases.)

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to prove part two: set inclusion. The proof is mostly definition chasing.

Let $S \in \mathbf{P}[A]\cup \mathbf{P}[B]$. Then either $S \subseteq A$ or $S \subseteq B$. In either case, $S \in \mathbf{P}[A \cup B]$ by noting that $$S \subseteq A \implies S \subseteq A \cup B \implies S \in \mathbf{P}[A \cup B]$$

And symmetrically for $S \subseteq B$.

Comment: Is my proof rigorous enough? Because i just started on set theory and i am trying to proof base on cases using my understanding.

Comment: This problem does not call for a proof by cases. Also, you reasoning regarding "number of elements" (while it makes some sense in this context) does not generalize at all. Given that you are just starting set theory, it is best to get comfortable with formal proofs like those given by me and @drhab.

Answer (score 0):

We have $A\cup B\in\wp\left(A\cup B\right)$.

However $A\cup B\in\wp\left(A\right)\cup\wp\left(B\right)$
is true if and only if $A\cup B\subseteq A$ or $A\cup B\subseteq B$.

If $A-B$ and $B-A$ are both non-empty then this is not the case.

This proves that (i) is not true in general.

---

$X\in\wp\left(A\right)\cup\wp\left(B\right)$ is true if and only
if $X$ is a subset of $A$ or a subset of $B$.

In both cases $X$
is a subset of $A\cup B$ as well, i.e. $X\in\wp\left(A\cup B\right)$.

This
proves that (ii) is true in general.

Comment: Hi drhab, is my proof rigorous enough to answer the questions? I am trying to prove it through my understanding.

Comment: At (i) you must consider the case where $A$ is not a subset of $B$ **and** $B$ is not a subset of $A$. Secondly the word 'more' is not a proper term here. The conclusion must be that in that case $A\cup B$ is a set that belongs to the powerset of $A\cup B$ and has elements that do not belong to $A$ nor to $B$.

Comment: thank you drhab for your kind assistance! Much appreciated!

Comment: At (ii) the cases where $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$ are in principal okay. The other cases both deal with a set $A$ that has elements that do not belong to $B$. Your reasoning there is not okay. You are saying: 'the powerset of $A\cup B$ contains a set that has more elements than $A$ or $B$' and from that you conclude that the powersets of $A$ and $B$ are both contained in the powerset of $A\cup B$. Again the word 'more' is not proper. You should reason here: $A$ subset of $A\cup B$ so each subset of $A$ is subset of $A\cup B$ so powerset of $A$ is subset of powerset of ... For $B$ likewise.

Comment: Hi dr hab is it correct if i say power set of A union power set of B is equal to P(A U B)?

Comment: No, it is not. In (i) this was proved to be not true.